# Replacing an observations's NA value in a column with a specific string

Tags: r

This should be relatively simple, but I am new to R and the tidyverse. I have a dataframe that is the result of 5 (!) combined csvs that looks like this:

[image: Current result]

I want to combine the data to be only four rows, which would look like this:

[image: Desired Final Result]

Would you please help me create an if else statement to fill in the NAs in the columns? For example,

If "Division" column value for the observation = 1, write "DivisionName" value as "New England". Essentially I want to combine Division (number) with "DivisionName" and RegionNumber with "RegionName" to clean the data. Any insights would be apprecaited. I believe this can be done using dplyr, perhaps with transmute and bindrows. Thank you for helping someone who is learning to combine and rename multiple CSVs. Here's the code I have now:

```
library(tidyverse)
DS1 <- read.csv("./datafiles/Division_State-I.csv")
DS2 <- read.csv("./datafiles/Division_State-II.csv")
DS3 <- read.csv("./datafiles/Division_State-III.csv")
RD <- read.csv("./datafiles/Region_Division.csv")
Region <-read.csv("./datafiles/Region.csv")

DS123 <- bind_rows(DS1,DS2,DS3,RD,Region)
uniqueDS123 <- unique(DS123) %>%
  rename("Division"="DivisionNumber", "FIPS"="StateFIPS", "State"="StateName")
```

Comment: You should be using join operations instead of/in addition to `bind_rows`. As a guess, `bind_rows(DS1,DS2,DS3) %>% left_join(Region) %>% left_join(RD)`, but I'm not really sure what any of your raw files look like. It's unusual that using `bind_rows` on data frames with mostly different columns is useful.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would make a small **reproducible** example - instead of posting pictures of data, share 3-5 rows and the relevant columns in text/code that can by copy/pasted.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Gregor, when I run the code you posted I get `4: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector`. There are factors involved in the data frames. Here's what the source CVS look like: (DS 1:3) https://share.getcloudapp.com/YEuANJ9R, RD: https://share.getcloudapp.com/z8uXpB0b, Region: https://share.getcloudapp.com/04uK9R4m

Comment: Instead of asking me to download and read in files, would you post 3-5  rows of text in your question? If the DS1, DS2, DS3 files have the same structure, one example is enough. And it would be nice to see a few rows of `RD` and `Region` too. Simply enter `dput(DS1[1:5, ])` into your console---or if the result is too long try `dput(droplevels(DS1[1:5, ]))`---and copy/paste the result into your question. If you do that, some one can likely answer your question just by looking at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unite` to combine columns.

```
library(tidyr)

uniqueDS123 %>%
  unite(Division, Division, DivisionName, sep = "-", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  unite(Region, RegionNumber, RegionName, sep = "-", na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah, that is really helpful. I was looking at using unite . Unfortunately when I run the code you suggested, the observation values include NAs and not the RegionName or Division name. Do you know why that might be? https://share.getcloudapp.com/7KuR1ndb

Comment: @JacksonWalker Maybe those are factors. Try `uniqueDS123 %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  unite(Division, Division, DivisionName, sep = "-", na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  unite(Region, RegionNumber, RegionName, sep = "-", na.rm = TRUE)`. Also as Gregor mentioned consider adding data using `dput`. Screenshots are not helpful to debug an issue.

Comment: Thank you again @Ronak Shah, this really does get me closer: https://share.getcloudapp.com/YEuANJd9 However is there a way to add values to the rows that are missing the state or the DivisionName / RegionName? Maybe with an IF ELSE statement to fill in each line?

Comment: What do you want to replace `NA`'s with?

Comment: Can we somehow replace the observations with the DivisionNumber value of 1 to be "1 - New England for the Division column, and so on as seen here? https://share.getcloudapp.com/jkuKr8YR

Comment: It would be better if you create a dataframe with 2 columns 1 - New England and so on and then do a left_join on it.